# Add column to existing table using a query in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table that contains an ID and the income of an individual in Access. I now would like to add a column to this table that contains the income quintile (5%) the individual belongs to i.e. 1, 2, 3, ... depending on the individuals' income. 
I have calculated the upper limits of the quintiles from a different dataset and have stored them in another table.
Originally I planed to do this with a WHEN function in "calculate field" in the table view. However since I would like to use 5% quintiles I need 20 WHEN conditions which Access can't handle ("The function you have entered is too complex.").

Is there any way to do this with a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this with a `join`.  Assuming that the other table has these columns:

- quantile
- lowerbound
- upperbound

Then do:

```
select t.*,
       (select quantile
        from othertable as ot
        where t.value >= ot.lowerbound and t.value < ot.upperbound
       ) as quantile
from mytable as t;
```

The exact logic depends on the nature of your data (are the bounds inclusive or exclusive, for instance).  Your question provides no specifics, so this is guidance.

If you have a `quantile` column in the first table, you can also use a similar query to update the value.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt attention. This worked beautifully!